# Directive's templateUrl referencing div instead of entire HTML

Tags: angularjs

I've got a list of pop-ups/dialogs (enclosed in `div`s) that I want to place in a single HTML file and from there reference in different directives representing those pop-ups. As far as I know, AngularJS directive's templateUrl normally reference an HTML file. Is it possible to reference a single div within HTML for templateUrl? If it is, how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use the `template:` parameter instead of the `templateUrl:`?

Comment: @MichelTome I know I can use `template:`, but for the sake of 'cleanliness', I also want to place my many pop-ups in a single HTML file. If it's not possible I'll go with `template:` anyway.

Comment: See my answer then for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your template fragments are small, you can reference them from within your JS by using the `template:` parameter instead of `templateUrl:`. However, in my projects, I reference all the template partials by `templateUrl` and use a grunt task to preload all the individual HTML files into one Javascript file that is then loaded by Angular into the template cache. You can read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Add the div's as a `<script>` and add the attributes `type="text/ng-template"` and `id=""`, then when you set the `templateUrl:`, you pass the `id` from the script element.

Example:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/awesomeDiv.html">
   <div>
      (...)
   </div>
</script>
```

Directive:

`templateUrl: 'template/awesomeDiv.html'`

**NOTE:**
In order to use this, you need to have nested directives, so the parent directive includes your HTML with all `div`s, and the children uses the `ng-template`'d `div`s